# Self-hosting GitLab and Nextcloud on same device: tcp4 0.0.0.0:443: bind: address already in use

Tags: docker, gitlab, port, nextcloud

### Context

After installing a self-hosted instance of Nextcloud over https (accessible on: https://localhost:81 (and tor)), I am experiencing some difficulties running the self-hosted GitLab instance. When I run:

```bash
local output
    output=$(sudo docker run --detach \
      --hostname "$GITLAB_SERVER" \
      --publish "$GITLAB_PORT_1" --publish "$GITLAB_PORT_2" --publish "$GITLAB_PORT_3" \
      --name "$GITLAB_NAME" \
      --restart always \
      --volume "$GITLAB_HOME"/config:/etc/gitlab \
      --volume "$GITLAB_HOME"/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
      --volume "$GITLAB_HOME"/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
      -e GITLAB_ROOT_EMAIL="$GITLAB_ROOT_EMAIL_GLOBAL" -e GITLAB_ROOT_PASSWORD="$gitlab_pwd" -e EXTERNAL_URL="http://127.0.0.1" \
      "$gitlab_package")
```

with:

```
GITLAB_SERVER="127.0.0.1"
GITLAB_SERVER_HTTP_URL="http://$GITLAB_SERVER"
GITLAB_PORT_1="443:443"
GITLAB_PORT_2="80:80"
GITLAB_PORT_3="23:22"
```

I receive output:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint gitlab (426dd7fa772f5250531ca478760080f981287048023b356bfa0e98f16db347f9): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:443: bind: address already in use
```

I am aware this means some process is already running on port 443, and I wrote a method to kill everything running on those ports, however, the `httpd` process keeps respawning. Since I do this on a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04, I assume this is the Nextcloud process that keeps respawning. So I could kill and remove Nextcloud, however that defeats the purpose.

### Question

Hence, I would like to ask, how can I host both Nextcloud and GitLab on the same device, over HTTPS?

### Note

I am aware that the GitLab server at the time of writing still says `http` instead of `https`, I did not get to switching to `https` yet, as I encountered this error first.
I assume both need to be accessible at/via port 443, as they will both be accessible of tor via `https` with self-signed `SLL` certificates.

Comment: "I assume both need to be accessible at/via port 443" only one program can listen on one address/port combination.  put a web server on that port (apache or nginx) have it do virtual hosting based on the http host passed via SNI and then redirect to gitlab and nextcloud running on different ports on localhost

Answer (score 1):

For this reason you can use:

```
nginx['custom_nginx_config'] = "include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;"
```

section in `gitlab.rb`
and put in place nexcloud config `/etc/nginx/conf.d/nexcloud.conf`
It will help you to take all config on the same 443 port.
And then you can check your configs

```
 gitlab-ctl restart nginx
 gitlab-ctl status nginx
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! One challenge I am experiencing, is that the `gitlab.rb` is not created before running the `sudo docker run --detach ...` command, hence I do not yet know how to add the `nginx['custom_nginx_config']` property you specify. Would you happen to have a suggestion on how to include it, and what to put in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/nexcloud.conf`?

Comment: It should store in your folder `--volume "$GITLAB_HOME"/config:/etc/gitlab \`, so gitlab.rb are in there. After modification, you should do 
```docker exec -it $GITLAB_NAME bash
   gitlabctl-reconfigure
```